# How to continue jQuery Function

Tags: html, jquery

I am using the following code to change href links in a page to a new link by using their id.

This is what I'm using to find the href and add the id to it;

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('a[href$="/truck-bed-covers/camper-tops"]').attr('id', 'camper1');
});
```

And this is what I'm using to change the link.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("#camper1").attr("href", "../camper-tops");
});
```

It works great.  Except it doesn't continue on the rest of the page.  It only changes one link and then it's done.  How do I continue until there is no more links to change?

Comment: You need to use `.each()` to loop through the elements .. Also ID must be unique so don't use same id for more than one element

Comment: I saw that but where do I put it exactly in my code?  Do I replace 'ready' with 'each'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID has to be unique, else JavaScript works with the first one only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href$="/truck-bed-covers/camper-tops"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href", "../camper-tops");
    });
});
```

But I don't think this is the right way. You should find place where you create incorrect links and repair it there (in PHP/DB or where links came from).

Comment: Thanks Pavel, the problem is that I don't have access to any of that unfortunately and have to change them on my own.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you're adding the ID so you can refer to the element in the second line, but you don't need to. Once you have an element you can work on it.

You can select all links with something like `$('a[href]')` (all links with an href attribute) and then iterate over all of them with jQuery's `each` function. Something like

```
$(function(){ // shorthand for $(document).ready()
    $('a[href]').each(function(index, element){
        // work on each element here
        var $el = $(element);
        $el.attr('href', $el.attr('href').replace(/*whatever you want to do here */);
    });
});
```

Comment: But like @pavel says, smells like you're treating a symptom rather than the root cause.

Comment: @BrandonStone is it _just_ the links to "camper tops" you're wanting to change, or is it all links in the page? your selector `$('a[href$="/truck-bed-covers/camper-tops"]')` will only find `<a>` tags with that specific link. Also, you should take a look at the docs for `replace` to see how to use that properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace